# Smallest distance search in series of points

Tags: sql, search, optimization, indexing, distance

The main object is, given the series of points, find the closest ones in the huge database.
Lets say we have series s1 = ((X1, Y1), (X2, Y2), (X3, Y3), (X4, Y4)) = (P1, P2, P3, P4), table seriesOfPoints(IndexId, P1, P2, P3, P4) and given number Eta (maximum distance). What index should I create to optimize this query:

SELECT IndexId FROM seriesOfPoints
WHERE dist(P1, p1) + dist(P2, p2) + dist(P3, p3) + dist(P4, p4) < Eta

dist(P, p) = sqrt((x-X)^2+(y-Y)^2).
Desired index would be R-tree based, but, as far as I searched, there is no such index in SQL Server. How could I improve this query?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no database indexes that helps improving the performance of that query. Since your selection (`WHERE` clause)  is based on a functional, all rows must be tested to verify if the condition is true or not.

You could add a computed column (see [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx)) on the table with the whole formula 
(`dist(P1,p1) + dist(P2, p2) + dist(P3, p3) + dist(P4, p4)`). Then you can create an index over this new column.

After that, your `WHERE` clause will be just a simple `less than` condition with no functions.
Maybe this could improve your query.

Comment: How about max(dist()) < ETa? Should I index every point column then?

Comment: I didn't understand the comment.

Comment: Searching for series which qualifies condition: dist(P1, p1) < Eta AND dist(P2, p2) < Eta AND dist(P3, p3) < Eta AND dist(P4, p4) < Eta would spatial indexes boost the performance?

Comment: You can put indexes just over columns. So, indexes over the points don't bring any value to the performance, as all the rows will be checked, one by one. The idea is to remove the function from the query.